# Cardinality of the Stabilizer of the first canonical basis vector in special linear group over the integers

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

Let $k > 1$ be an integer. Let $e \in \mathbb{Z}^k$ be the element that has 1 in the first coordinate and 0 in every other coordinate. What is the cardinality of the stabilizer of $e$ in $\mathrm{SL}_k(\mathbb{Z})$ with respect to the natural action?

In other words, how many elements of $\mathrm{SL}_k(\mathbb{Z})$ with $e$ as the first column are there?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, the answer is "countably infinite". If $M \in \mathrm{SL}_{k}(\mathbb{Z})$ is a matrix whose first column is $e = [1 \; 0 \; \dotsb \; 0]^{\mathrm{T}}$, then the lower-right $(k-1) \times (k-1)$ submatrix of $M$ is an element of $\mathrm{SL}_{k-1}(\mathbb{Z})$, and the first row of $M$ can have arbitrary elements in entries $(1,2)$ to $(1,k)$.

For example in case $k=2$, such $M$ must be of the form $$ M = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & a_{12} \\ 0 & a_{22} \end{bmatrix} $$ where $[a_{22}] \in \mathrm{SL}_{1}(\mathbb{Z})$ so $a_{22} = 1$, but $a_{12}$ can be any element of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you. I was actually asking this about a problem pertaining to Haar measures, so this is very helpful. Thanks again!